# Require input regarding JAVA ENUMS

Tags: java, enums

Consider the following

```
public enum  tc implements  {
  NORESULTS(0), GOOD_RESULTS(1), EXCELLENT_RESULTS(2), NO_DATA_AVAILABLE(5), SOME_OTHER_VALUE(4);
    private final Integer value;
    // Code for the constructor, getters and setters for the value****
```

The enum `tc` values correspond to the testValue in the below class.

```
    public class TestData {
       private int testID;
       private String testName;
       private int testValue;
       ....
      ...

    }
```

In the Results class, the TestDataList has to be sorted by a different order of ranking rather than testValue.For example Excellent followed by Good Results followed by NoResults etc..

```
public class Results {

List<TestData> TestDataList = getTestData();
```

I can code for the comparator etc..the question is since I require a different ordering for the enums which of the following two options is better
a) add private int rankTestValue in the enum tc. This option may require that I have to write a method getRank(int value) that would return the corresponding rankTestValue based on the value.

OR
b) add in Results class a map Map tcRankMap = new HashMap();. Populate this map with key values like (2,1) (1,2) corresponding to (enum values, ranking).For example (2,1) would be Excellent_Results has first ranking etc.

Which of these two options would be better. If there are better solutions then please let me know.

Comment: So you want to sort `TestData` instances based on `tc` values but the `tc` values have an order that is not fix?

Comment: I don't understand why `testValue` is declare as `int` rather than `tc`. Can you explain?

Comment: So really your question is 'what is an elegant way to define a comparator for an enum that is different from it's natural ordering?' Right?

Answer (score 0):

Option (a) looks better and according to Object Oriented Analysis and Design.

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that the is a question of implementation detail which can be encapsulated into your `Comparator` anyway, so it doesn't matter so much.

As for style and readability, I would prefer (a), but it's down to personal preference.

There is also a solution (c) - use the `ordinal()`, and then sort them according to rank. Just add a comment to make it clear

```
public enum  tc implements  {
    // NB: enum values are sorted according to rank
    EXCELLENT_RESULTS(2),
    GOOD_RESULTS(1),
    NORESULTS(0),
    NO_DATA_AVAILABLE(5),
    SOME_OTHER_VALUE(4);

    private final Integer value;
    // Code for the constructor, getters and setters for the value****
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first option would look like this:

```
enum TestScore {
    EXCELLENT(5),
    NO_RESULT(2),
    POOR(1);
    private final int order;
    private TestScore(int order) {
        this.order = order;
    }
    public int compareOrderTo(TestScore other) {
        return this.order - other.order;
    }
}
```

You could then add a comparison method to TestData

```
public int compareTestScore(TestData other) {
    return this.testScore.compareOrderTo(other.testScore);
}
```

And sort your list with:

```
Collections.sort(testData, TestData::compareTestScore);
```

The problem with this is that the `order` field is really completely arbitrary and needs to be updated each time you add a new entry. However that's definitely better and more explicit than using the natural ordering of the enum (i.e. it's ordinal value which should be entirely incidental to avoid fragility).